# Add successive dropdown menus with n-1 choices after a choice is selected

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple dropdown menu in my tabbed window using `QComboBox`.

```
def tab1UI(self):
  layout = QFormLayout()
  self.cb = QComboBox()
  self.cb.addItems(["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option5", "Option6"])
  layout.addWidget(self.cb)
  self.setTabText(0,"Search")
  self.tab1.setLayout(layout)
```

What I want to do is add another menu whenever an option is selected.

Say the user selects `Option3`. Once they do so, I want to add a menu below which no longer has `option3` to choose from and has a `No Selection` option in its place. Successive menus will continue to be added added until the user chooses `No Selection`. How would I do this?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: You know which option is selected.  You make a new list without that option and use it for the basis of the new menu Widget.  Please try coding that, and explain more specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I am not sure how to determine which option the user has selected. There is a way to find this and bind it to an action, I am just not sure how. Hence the question.

Comment: *Not* hence the question.  You want to react to a click in on menu for which you have the object handle and full inspection rights.  This is easily researched on line with examples and tutorials, so we *assume* that you know the approach before you post here.  Again, read the posting guidelines to which I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace everything with variables to make it much easier to manipulate. Here is an example. I am not familiar with the module you are using (apparently it is `QComboBox`), so my code might have a few errors. 
**Begin code:**

```
def tab1UI(self):
  layout = QFormLayout()
  self.cb = QComboBox()
  items=["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option5", "Option6"]
  self.cb.addItems(items)
  layout.addWidget(self.cb)
  self.setTabText(0,"Search")
  self.tab1.setLayout(layout)
  #Here you would put a way to record which option the user selects, lets say "selected"
  selected=#Option user selects
  items=items.replace(selected, "No Selection") #This replaces the selected option with "No Selection"
  #Here you would insert the new menu, I think it is this way:
  layout = QFormLayout()
  self.cb = QComboBox()
  self.cb.addItems(items)
  layout.addWidget(self.cb)
  self.setTabText(0,"Search")
  self.tab1.setLayout(layout)
```